# function application with lambda in haskell?

Tags: haskell, lambda, quickcheck

Having this code to test:

```
-- | this function checks if string or list are a palindrome
    isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
    isPalindrome x =
        if reverse x == x
            then True
            else False
```

I managed to write this:

```
-- | how do I remove ugly parentheses our of here?
palindromeTest verb = isPalindrome ((\verb -> verb ++ reverse verb) verb )  == True
    where types = verb::String
```

Parentheses look disgusting, how do I work them out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `palindromeTest`

Your expression:

```
(\verb -> verb ++ reverse verb) verb
```

does not make much sense: an equivalent expression would be:

```
(\x -> x ++ reverse x) verb
```

since `verb` in the lambda expression was locally scoped. But you know what `x` is: it is `verb`. So you can replace the expression with:

```
verb ++ reverse verb
```

Or in full:

```
palindromeTest verb = isPalindrome (verb ++ reverse verb) == True
```

We can also eliminate the `== True`, since `\x -> x == True` is equivalent to `id`:

```
palindromeTest verb = isPalindrome (verb ++ reverse verb)
```

Finally the `where types = verb::String` is useless as well: Haskell is statically typed, types are resolved at compile time. So this statement does not adds anything. You can restrict the type of verb in the type signature of the function:

```
palindromeTest :: String -> Bool
palindromeTest verb = isPalindrome (verb ++ reverse verb)
```

## `isPalindrome`

Just like in `palindromTest` it is useless to write `== True`, there is no reason to write `= True`, and `= False` if this is based on a condition: simply return the condition itself:

```
-- | this function checks if string or list are a palindrome
isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome x = reverse x == x
```

You can make it more compact by using `ap`:

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

-- | this function checks if string or list are a palindrome
isPalindrome :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isPalindrome = ap (==) reverse
```

Comment: types is there for QuickCheck

Comment: @kaboom: that does not matter: quicktest is nothing special: it creates a Haskell executable as well, so it passes through the compiler as well.

Comment: werid, I was under impression it's required, based off QuickCheck tutorial. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @kaboom: can you show where this is written in the tutorial?